# does JRockit mission control 4.1 support SUN hotspot (hot spot) JVM?

Tags: jboss, jvm, jvm-hotspot, jrockit

i can see some documents in Oracle site said: "JRockit Mission Control 4.1 is now available for download. It includes HotSpot support, improved Solaris support, DTrace integration, a Mac OSX port, support for Oracle Coherence and a range of new cool features. More details in Markus Eisele's blog post."

but acually i can not use jrmc to connect to my JBoss application running on SUN HotSpot JVM, any help? many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From offical JRockit webpage: 
The Oracle JRockit Mission Control client can now be run on Oracle HotSpot JVM. JRockit Mission Control can also start the local management on Hotspot JDK 1.6 and later. **Note that you will still need to connect to a JRockit to be able to use most of the Mission Control tools.**

Answer (score 1):

If you are an Oracle customer, you can download early versions of Java Mission Control 5.x (Mission Control for Hotspot) from MOS (My Oracle Support). You will need to run a recent version of the Oracle JDK 7 (>= 7u4). Please note that there are still a lot of limitations, as described here: http://hirt.se/blog/?p=211.